# Error while running pycassa setup on Win 7

Tags: python, django, django-models, cassandra, pycassa

Im trying to use Pycassa-1.3.0 with DJango and cassandra-1.0.5, Cassandra is working but running Pycassa Setup (python setup.py) gives me error 404,

here are the traces:

```
Downloading http://pypi.python.org/packages/2.7/s/setuptools/setuptools-0.6c9-py
2.7.egg
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 16, in <module>
    use_setuptools()
  File "C:\pycassa-1.3.0\ez_setup.py", line 95, in use_setuptools
    return do_download()
  File "C:\pycassa-1.3.0\ez_setup.py", line 89, in do_download
    egg = download_setuptools(version, download_base, to_dir, download_delay)
  File "C:\pycassa-1.3.0\ez_setup.py", line 150, in download_setuptools
    src = urllib2.urlopen(url)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 126, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 400, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 513, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 438, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 372, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 521, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you don't have setuptools installed, and so it's trying to install setuptools for you, but the default version it looks for is a little old, and so the link no longer works.

I'll update pycassa to fix the problem, but in the meantime you have a couple of options:

- Install setuptools manually
- Change the `DEFAULT_VERSION` in `ez_setup.py` to be "0.6c11"